# Execute a script second time around if it fails on the first attempt?

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts. Here is the first script; `health.js`

```
var health : float = 5.0;
var combo : float = 6.0;
function Start () {

}

function Update () {

}
```

and here is the second script; `attack.js`

```
function Start () {

}

function Update () {

if(Input.GetKeyDown("1")) {

combo +=5;

}

}
```

But there is a problem - `combo +=5;` gives error : `Assets/attack.js(10,1): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'combo'`. so how can i solve this ? please help me I don't want these in same script

Comment: ***why is everything bold-italic?***

Comment: `var health : float = 5.0;` are you using TypeScript or don't you even know the basics of JS?

Comment: @LightStyle I don't think this is JavaScript.... The error doesn't seem right either

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you should format float like this:

```
var combo = 0.5;
```

You need to load `health.js` before `attack.js`.
In addtion, you can set up an if statement to find out if combo is set.

```
if(combo !== undefined) {
     combo +=5;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that in older environments there is the possibility to change the value of `undefined`. A better way to check it would be to test if `typeof combo !== "undefined"`.

Comment: @LightStyle That's really not necessary - all modern browsers have `undefined` as read-only and why would you set it to something else anyway?

Comment: @Asaf This answer is wrong because of scope. -1

Comment: I know, in fact I have specified *in older environments*. Because there are yet lame scripts in the world :P

Comment: @Doorknob what do you mean by scope?

Comment: @Asaf The other file will not be able to see the variable, because it is not in scope. You could fix it by making it global by removing the `var`

Comment: Wrong, just the create 2 files and the  combo is a global variable.
file 1:
var number = 1.2;
file 2:
function showNumber() {
alert(number);
}

Comment: Hmm, okay then. I made an edit so I could remove my downvote